# NoSQL database representation on diagram

Tags: mongodb, nosql

How can I show a structure of `NoSQL` database on diagram (or another approach)?

I use MongoDB

Answer (score 0):

Couple of options

1)
You can use http://hackolade.com/ for mongodb , cassandra , dynamodb. Used it around 1 month back.

2)
You can used Compass from Mongodb itself (available only on enterprise editions)